# T-SQL query to get the string between two special characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I wanted to extract a word between two special characters. I tried to use the trim and substring functions but the results aren't the expected one.

Input:

```
viewpointops\Leslie.cullum.7M5
```

Output needed:

```
Leslie.cullum
```

I tried `select SUBSTRING(c2,0,CHARINDEX('\',c2))` from table used this query to save viewpointops\ in a variable and similarly for the rest of the inputs. It was a long query and not an efficient one as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post what did you try

Comment: select SUBSTRING(c2,0,CHARINDEX('\',c2))
from table

used this query to save viewpointops\ in a variable and similarly for the rest of the inputs. It was a long query and not an efficient one as well.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps:

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(100) = ' viewpointops\Leslie.cullum.7M5';

SELECT txt = SUBSTRING(s.s1, 1, CHARINDEX('.', s.s1, d.d1)-1)
FROM (VALUES (SUBSTRING(@string, CHARINDEX('\',@string)+1, 8000))) s(s1)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CHARINDEX('.',s.s1)+1)) d(d1);
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks Alan.

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern is somewhat consistent with the sample

**Example**

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(100) = ' viewpointops\Leslie.cullum.7M5';

select parsename(replace(parsename(@S,3),'\','.'),1)+'.'+parsename(@S,2)
```

**Returns**

```
Leslie.cullum
```

Comment: like the trick of using PARSENAME, I have used it for something similar in the past.  @jinglyhk paresename is specifically for getting parts of a SQL object name and because you schema is using 2 periods (3) name parts it works. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it if pulling data from a table.

```
DECLARE @data TABLE ( [value] VARCHAR(255) );
INSERT INTO @data ( [value] ) VALUES ( ' viewpointops\Leslie.cullum.7M5' );

SELECT
    SUBSTRING( 
        x.val -- value to parse.
        , 1   -- starting position.
        , LEN( x.val) - CHARINDEX( '.', REVERSE( x.val ) ) -- gets the length of the value to return.
    ) AS MyParsedVal
FROM ( 

    -- return everything after the backslash for easier parsing ( assumes there is only 1 as in your example ).
    SELECT 
        SUBSTRING( [value], CHARINDEX( '\', [value] ) + 1, CHARINDEX( '\', REVERSE( [value] ) ) ) AS val
    FROM @data

) AS x;
```

Returns

```
+---------------+
|  MyParsedVal  |
+---------------+
| Leslie.cullum |
+---------------+
```